# How many four digit numbers have this property?(3 digit factors)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

*"How many four-digit numbers have the following property? “For each of its digits, when this digit is
deleted the resulting three-digit number is a factor of the original number.”*

 Is there anyway to come up with an answer without relying on coding, thank you.

$my~attempt:$
$$let~abcd~be~a~4~digit~number~\\\frac{abcd}{bcd} ~-note: as~it~could~be~any~3~digit~number\\\frac{a}{bcd}+1$$
*how could you move on from here?*

Comment: You should not "$a$" in $\frac a{bcd}$ as $a000$.

Comment: Start by showing that the units digit must be zero. Or start by doing some warmup questions: how many two-digit numbers have the property that deleting any digit leaves a factor? How many three-digit numbers have this property?

Comment: A quick computer search finds:  *None*.

Answer (score 0):

Let the four digit number be $x=1000a+100b+10c+d$, we know that
$$100b+10c+d |x$$
$$1000a+10c+d|x$$
$$1000a+100b+d|x$$
$$1000a+100b+10c|x$$
Denote $x_n$ as the number obtained when removing the $n$th digit (counting from the left). Let's start with the first one: 
$$x=1000a+x_1\equiv0 \pmod{x_1} \implies x_1|1000a$$ 
Similarly, we get
$$x_2|100b, x_3|10c, x_4|d$$
Whoa, hold on. $x_4=(1000a+100b+10c)|d$? Nonsense. Oh, except of course if $d=0$, applying this we also get $x_3=(1000a+100b)|10c$, another nonsense. Successively repeating this argument yields $a=b=c=d=0$

Comment: 8800, is a number which goes against your solution, similarly any number of the form $ab00$, but i'm looking for a proof which shows this.Thank you for your reply.